# How does multiprocessing.dummy.Pool in Python work?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I'm using multiprocessing.dummy.Pool in one of my programs. The documentation at https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map says the following:

> This method chops the iterable into a number of chunks which it submits to the process pool as separate tasks. The (approximate) size of these chunks can be specified by setting chunksize to a positive integer.

1. How does it chop the iterable into a number of chunks? What are the default sizes of the chunks?

> Note that it may cause high memory usage for very long iterables.

2. How does it cause high memory usage for long iterables? How do I decide what would be the best chunksize to keep to avoid this?

Comment: Note that the second comment is not related to the chunksize. The "problem" is that ``map`` produces *all* results as one list – which can grow large if there are many results. As the linked docs state, use ``imap`` or ``imap_unordered`` instead to produce results one after the other.

Comment: test it with some data and see how big chunks it uses - or find source code and check in code. I would expect that default size is `1` and I would expect it use `iterate[:chunksize]` or something similar to get one chunk

Comment: you can get path to source code `pool.py` using `print(multiprocessing.pool.__file__)` and you will see `map()` is using function `_map_async()` which calculates default size `chunksize, extra = divmod(len(iterable), len(self._pool) * 4)`